# Why doesn't Preview on Mac respect the "read only" flag in PDF files?

Tags: python, django, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfrw

I'm working on a django project using pdfrw to fill a fillable pdf form.

I'm setting the `Ff = 1` flag in order to make the fields read-only.

```
for annotation in template_path.Root.AcroForm.Fields:
    #  the code goes here
    annotation.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(Ff=1))
```

This seems to work in every viewer I tested so far except for "Preview" the native mac app to open and display pdf files.

Why is that? Am I missing something? Is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score -1):

You are not missing anything.

Preview.app is POISON for fillable forms. This piece of s**tware must be avoided at all price in connection with forms.

Workaround: have your users use something useful, such as Adobe Acrobat (Reader).

Comment: Wow, that's emotional... ;)

Comment: And that from someone noodling around with Macs for more than 30 years…

Comment: Do you know if there is  a way of getting the field location on the page using pdfrw?